Linux emergency mode is not exitable
I have a problem with installing linux on another SSD drive. The reason is i bought new ssd and i want to bring my current system with all settings and programs, and move it to the new drive. Steps i followed to reach this aim:

On my current drive created linux snapshot using Timeshift.
Saved this snapshot on USB Drive
Plugged in my new SSD drive
Installed clear linux on it
Using the USB found system snapshot, and started unpacking it on that SSD (or I don't now how to replace "unpacking" here. It means i was trying to apply all settings and programs on new system)
After this step, i rebooted my PC, and after long loading, i saw system emergency screen.

Since this, i have been trying to run all commands: systemctl reboot, default or exit, and any of this commands brings me to the same screen. I opened a journal, and scrolling down found some orange code lines, which are possible errors, and way cause emergency mode. But at thus stage i really don't know what should I do.
My main goal is to restore my previous linux settings on new SSD (as i was said before)
I would really appreciate your suggestions and possible solutions for this situation!

It seems you over-complicated what would be a simple backup & restore of personal files job, considering you "installed Linux on another drive".

So i need to bring all my system on another drive not in such way?

We don't know. If you don't know what you're doing how can anyone else know? Perhaps you should [edit] the question to clarify. So far I inferred you 1. want to install the OS in another drive; 2. you used timeshift; 3. you installed the OS as intended; 4. you did something with your timeshift backup (very likely you overwrote everything that you did before because that is the purpose of timeshift).

Yes, sorry but the sentence "I needed to load my Linux on another drive" is very unclear. Are you trying to copy an existing Linux installation to a new machine? Are you using a new drive in the same machine and want to copy data over? Then, you mention errors, OK, but what errors? We can't help if you don't show them. So please edit your question, clarify that first sentence so we can understand what you are trying to do, and then show the errors you found in the logs.

I've changed this tread so you may see all situation clearly!

Indeed, as expected. Timeshift is not for cloning. By "unpacking" you overwrote what you installed. You could have cloned using the proper tools (e.g. Clonezilla) then resize the partition if needed - or - much better, simply backed up your personal files and eventually some settings (not always a good idea if you install a different Linux, even a newer release of the same distro), install in the new drive (as you ended up doing anyway) and then copy back from the backups.

Thank you so much, I'm newbie, and my friend said that it could work for this purpose ( using timeshift for clonning Linux). Now i understand what should i do. Thanks!

Is there still a question here? If so, please edit your question to put everything of import there. You should not be adding details on the comments

No there isn't, but i don't know how to close it
